# Faucet Stem is Totally Stuck on Faucet Housing

Tags: faucet, bathroom-fixtures, stuck

I am having a problem with my bathroom shower faucets. I have a leak in my bathroom shower taps. I have a Jameco faucet and I found new stems for the hot and cold. replaces the hot water side with no problems...then I started on the cold water side and the stem was totally stuck to the housing. It was so stuck that when I used penetrating oil and gave it some force, the whole housing came undone. I have tried everything to get the stem loose to no avail. The guy at the hardware store told me that maybe a mechanic would be able to get it loose. I thought that maybe I could just buy a new seat and housing and everything would be good but now I found out from the supply store that I cant get a new housing...just the seat. So Im at my wits ens as to what to do with this. Ive been told NOT to heat the stem as it will make the problem worse. Does anyone have any ideas with regards to this ? Any help is greatly appreciated !

Comment: I just replaced some stem assemblies like this in a neighbor's shower but it was a different mfgr. The part I replaced was the entire stem assembly not just the stem. This entire assembly has to be removed to change the washer and the seat. Do you have this entire part removed so you can see the brass seat and can change the washer? If you do want to remove the stem from this assembly, you would unscrew the packing nut to loosen the stem and would turn the stem *in, in, in* until is is free of the outer fitting. You would then insert a new stem by doing the reverse.

Comment: Do you have just the stem? Do you have a new packing nut? Is the old packing nut frozen to the outer fitting? In the parts I replaced the outer fitting of the stem assembly screws into the valve body of the shower.

Comment: Image address for a type of shower valve is below. Is this what you have?  https://guideimg.alibaba.com/images/shop/72/08/19/9/fit-price-pfister-two-handle-shower-faucet-repair-kit-by-plumb-usa-and-faucet888_3209419.jpg

Comment: Hi Jim... the old stem for the faucet is totally stuck to the housing. I have the entire housing out. I can see the seat but I can't get it out of the housing. I have a new stem and I can get a new seat but the housing I cannot seem to find which I need in order to put any new parts in. My problem lays with the old stem being stuck to the housing. If I could find a new Jameco housing I would be home free but I haven't had any luck at all in finding a new housing piece.

Answer (score 0):

The part I called the outer fitting and I think you are calling the housing is evidently called the "gland". Do you have the stem-packing nut-gland assembly removed from the body of the shower mixing valve?
[image]

Follow this link: [https://www.google.com/search?q=names+for+parts+of+a+valve+stem+for+a+shower&biw=1094&bih=487&tbm=isch&imgil=QrVCXmPyvaHfuM%253A%253BCv-TkN5uWlEcUM%253Bhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.plumbingsupply.com%25252Fmixet.html&source=iu&pf=m&fir=QrVCXmPyvaHfuM%253A%252CCv-TkN5uWlEcUM%252C_&usg=__NfYVX-8AQeLqTwKxoqN4wEETSEc%3D&ved=0ahUKEwiB9L7tu7PRAhWqqlQKHaQOBvgQyjcIJw&ei=yKtyWIHwDKrV0gKknZjADw#imgrc=_](https://www.google.com/search?q=names%20for%20parts%20of%20a%20valve%20stem%20for%20a%20shower&biw=1094&bih=487&tbm=isch&imgil=QrVCXmPyvaHfuM%253A%253BCv-TkN5uWlEcUM%253Bhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.plumbingsupply.com%25252Fmixet.html&source=iu&pf=m&fir=QrVCXmPyvaHfuM%253A%252CCv-TkN5uWlEcUM%252C_&usg=__NfYVX-8AQeLqTwKxoqN4wEETSEc%3D&ved=0ahUKEwiB9L7tu7PRAhWqqlQKHaQOBvgQyjcIJw&ei=yKtyWIHwDKrV0gKknZjADw#imgrc=_)